# (Jhipster)Application stops working without throwing any error

Tags: jhipster

I've one application which is running live. It runs really well but sometimes it stops working without throwing any error in the logs. I've made this application using Jhipster. I'm really looking for some best answer for the related question so that my users can access my application without facing any issue. So, I'm listing down some errors which I found on my boxfuse console.

> com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.PlatformApplicationDisabledException:
>   Platform application is disabled (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code:
>   400; Error Code: PlatformApplicationDisabled;

Comment: You should rather contact Boxfuse support or tag your question accordingly because I can't imagine how it would be related to JHipster.

Comment: I've created my application using JHipster. The thing is I'm unable to track the issue which makes my application slow or shut down without displaying any error in the logs.

Comment: Slow then shutdown looks like a memory issue, how did you configure your java memory options?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I'm deploying my application on boxfuse using aws

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Like I'm still confused. This is happening just from few months ago before that my application was running absolutely fine without shutting down or getting slow at any point.

Comment: THESE are the responses I got from github community but still unable to handle it :                                                                                                                                      PlatformApplicationDisabledException is returned from the service. You need to reach out to service team via AWS Forums to investigate why token is being rejected. As per this post, this might be caused by expired credential.

Comment: That error is returned when the platform has rejected the token.

The SDK appears to be handling this error correctly.

Comment: Kindly help me resolve this issue if possible thankyou

Comment: Exception while sending pushcom.amazonaws.services.sns.model.EndpointDisabledException: Endpoint is disabled (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code:

Comment: I wonder if I'm doing something wrong in my program or if these errors could be handled by amazon aws.

Comment: 2018-12-20 18:41:54.672  INFO 70712 --- [           main] c.u.frother.security.jwt.TokenProvider   : Invalid JWT token.

Comment: Is there anyone who can guide me through to resolve this issue asap.